# Unknown directive "model" when setting up AWS Amplify GraphQL in Android

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-amplify

I've been trying to set up GraphQL for my android kotlin project with AWS Amplify, but I am getting red warning for @model as well as AuthRule & allow in:

[image]

This is the example TODO GraphQL schema, but when I do edit the schema, the issue still occurs. I'm wondering if I am missing something else that I didn't see in the documentation?

When I hover over @model, I see a **Unknown directive "model"** error message.

I tried to uninstalling and installing again the *amplify add api*. The error continues, and after searching through online, I don't see any solutions that are recent that can help with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found that there was a JS GraphQL Plugin that was causing the red errors to occur in the Android Project. Just had to disable it.